# Phoenix controller action refactor

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following action in my Phoenix app controller:

```
defmodule TattooBackend.Web.API.V1.StudioController do
  use TattooBackend.Web, :controller

  alias TattooBackend.Repo
  alias TattooBackend.Accounts.Account

  def index(conn, params) do
    studios = Studio

    studios = if params["search"] do
      Studio.search(studios, params["search"])
    end

    studios = studios |> Repo.all |> Repo.preload(:address)

    render conn, studios: studios
  end
end
```

Is there any way to refactor this code to be more readable?

Comment: Does this even work correctly when `params` doesn't have `"search"`? `studios` would become `nil` in that case as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code wouldn't work when `params["search"]` is falsy. If it is falsy, `studios` will get the value `nil`.

You can do this more elegantly like this:

```
studios =
  if params["search"] do
    Studio.search(Studio, params["search"])
  else
    Studio
  end
  |> Repo.all
  |> Repo.preload(:address)
```

The `if` can be collapsed into a single line as well:

```
studios =
  if(params["search"], do: Studio.search(Studio, params["search"]), else: Studio)
  |> Repo.all
  |> Repo.preload(:address)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build more complex queries by `reduce` over the params, eg allowing the address to be conditionally included:

```
query = 
  Enum.reduce(params, Studio, fn 
    {"search", search_term}, query -> Studio.search(query, search_term)
    {"include_address", "true"}, query -> Ecto.Query.preload(query, :address)
    # ... additional query building params handled here
    _, query -> query # ignore unrecognised params
  end)

studios = Repo.all(query)
render conn, studios: studios
```